# more than one elements with same class gsap

Tags: javascript, animation, gsap, scrolltrigger

I'm working on GSAP and I have two elements on different pages that have the same class and I want to apply their animation using scrollTrigger when I reach the element. Is there a way I can do this with a function instead of giving them a specific class and repeating myself?

Here is my code:

##### HTML:

```html
 <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="containe">
        <img class="image" src="./card-1.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <img class="image" src="./card-2.png" alt="">
    </div>
```

##### CSS:

```css
.container{
 height: 100vh;
}
```

##### GSAP:

```js
gsap.to('.image' ,{
    x:500,
    rotation:250,
    duration:1,
    opacity:1,
    scrollTrigger:{
        trigger:'.image',
        start:'top center',
        toggleActions:'restart none none none',
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you don't need to repeat the code for the same class; just put GSAP javascript in a single js file and call it anywhere you want. Also, you can use the same class on a single page and scroll trigger them separately:

**1.** By using [`toArray()`](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/UtilityMethods/toArray()) method:

```js
var sections = gsap.utils.toArray(".image");

sections.forEach((section) => {
  gsap.to(section, {
    x: 500,
    rotation: 250,
    duration: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: section,
      end: "-=500",
      scrub: true,
      toggleActions: "restart none none none",
    },
  });
});
```

tweak `start` / `end`  points for best result.
[Example Pen](https://codepen.io/akapowl/pen/bGegErw/1047b333ef8e501ecde9ceb4b58414e7)

**2.** you can also use [`ScrollTrigger.batch`](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger/static.batch())

```js
ScrollTrigger.batch(".image", {
  onEnter: (batch) =>
    gsap.to(batch, {
      x: 500,
      rotation: 250,
      duration: 1,
      opacity: 1,
    }),
});
```

You can also set `onLeave` animation.
Checkout [this Pen](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/zYrxpmb) for example